# EasyMock CXF JAXWS Client

Tags: jax-ws, cxf, easymock

I am trying to test my web service client which uses CXF with JAXWS annotations i.e. @WebService and @SOAPBinding. I was wondering is there a way to mock the interface which has these annotations? If I use EasyMock to mock it, it mocks the interface but ignores the functioality supplied by the annotations.

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `wsimport` from Java. Is more easy

this website can help you.

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/